# Java generics - The type parameter String is hiding the type String

Tags: java, generics

In my interface:

```
public <T> Result query(T query)
```

In my 1st subclass:

```
public <HashMap> Result query(HashMap queryMap)
```

In my 2nd subclass:

```
public <String> Result query(String queryStr)
```

1st subclass has no compilation warning at all while 2nd subclass has:
The type parameter String is hiding the type String? I understand my parameter is hidden by the generics type. But I want to understand underneath what exactly happened?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It thinks you're trying to create a type parameter -- a *variable* -- whose name is `String`.  I suspect your first subclass simply doesn't import `java.util.HashMap`.

In any event, if `T` is a type parameter of your *interface* -- which it probably should be -- then you shouldn't be including the `<String>` in the subclasses at all.  It should just be

```
public interface Interface<T> {
  public Result query(T query);
}

public class Subclass implements Interface<String> {
  ...
  public Result query(String queryStr) { 
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: As a style issue, I'd recommend against naming a type parameter `String` - or other commonly used Java class names. It will potentially confusing for anyone examining the code later on. If I see `String` in Java, I assume it's `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Oh, absolutely.  I suspect that the example I give here is what the OP _meant_ to do, though.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [this S&O question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011758/troubleshooting-the-type-parameter-t-is-hiding-the-type-t-warning).

Comment: Yeah, I perhaps should have commented on the question instead of on your answer. :-)

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is that, it's up to the subclass to decide whether they want to pass java.lang.String or java.util.HashMap as parameter to query() method. Interface just needs to say, subclasses have to implement query method, but I don't care about what type of parameter subclasses want to pass in. @oconnor0 Is your answer here best practice for this? or I should just use a wild card in the interface like query(?)

Comment: @Shengjie, I think the code sample I gave above matches that use case as well as it's going to get.  The subclass decides what type the query should have.

Comment: What about <T extends HashMap> ?