# Explain this Generics Behavior in JAVA

Tags: java, generics, extends

```
public class MyList<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    Node<Item> first;
    int n = 0;

    private static class Node<Item>
    {
        private Item item;
        private Node<Item> next;
    }
    public Iterator<Item> iterator()  {
        return new ListIterator<Item>();
    }

    private class ListIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item>  // parameter Item is hiding the type Item
    {
        private Node<Item> current = first;  // This does not compile

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (current != null);   
        }

        public Item next() {
            Item item = current.item;
            current = current.next;
            return current.item;
        }       
    }
    ...
}
```

The error I get is

> "Type Mismatch : can't convert from MyList.Node to
>   MyList.Node".

Not sure if this is related to the warning

> "paramter Item is hiding the type item"

If I get a warning for `private class ListIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item>`, why did I not get a warning for `public class MyList<Item> implements Iterable<Item>` ?

Answer (score 5):

If the generic type parameter of the inner class `ListIterator` should be the same as the type parameter of the enclosing class `MyList`, you shouldn't declare it twice.

Change the inner class to:

```
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item>
```

This way, the type of `first` and `current` will be the same.

As Michael commented, you'll have to change the construction of the `ListIterator` instance to:

```
public Iterator<Item> iterator()  {
    return new ListIterator();
}
```

Comment: @Michael missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The warning very much is related. Your generic type parameter in your inner class hides the generic type parameter in the outer class. So `Item` in each scope is not the same, hence the two different `Node<Item>`s are actually different types.

See also: [Troubleshooting "The type parameter T is hiding the type T" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011758/troubleshooting-the-type-parameter-t-is-hiding-the-type-t-warning)

Eran's answer shows how to fix it, so I won't repeat it.